# some questions when i installed Mechanize in ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I was on ubuntu 12.04 with ruby 1.8.7 and rubygem 1.8.15

First ,I type in `sudo gem install mechanize --no-ri --no-rdoc`

It seems working well.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: ntlm-http-0.1.1.gem (100%)
WARNING: ntlm-http-0.1.1 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
Fetching: webrobots-0.0.13.gem (100%)
Fetching: unf_ext-0.0.5.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: unf-0.0.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: domain_name-0.5.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: mechanize-2.5.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.5.5
Successfully installed ntlm-http-0.1.1
Successfully installed webrobots-0.0.13
Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.5
Successfully installed unf-0.0.5
Successfully installed domain_name-0.5.4
Successfully installed mechanize-2.5.1
7 gems installed
```

Then I wrote my first program

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
```

It just doesn't work

```
./mechanize.rb uninitialized constant Mechanize (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in        gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from mechanize.rb:2
```

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Rename your file to 'mechanize-test.rb' or something to avoid confusion with the library. It looks like 1.8's `require` is behaving strangely.

Comment: It's not require misbehaving but the way rails loads classes the file name is expected to be the class name so when you have mechanize.rb it expects to find the class name Mechanize in it, hence resulting in the uninitialized constant exception

Comment: @bjhaid - actually the problem is 1.8 loads mechanize.rb from `.` instead if the gem's folder because of `LOAD_PATH` issues. It's not a rails issue, there's no rails here.